# Simple Go concurrency example

Tags: go, concurrency

What would be a simple example of concurrency being used to increase execution speed? 
I've found a number of examples which use parallelism but none that just use concurrency.

Comment: First of all Go is designed for concurrency, not parallelism. You should take a look at https://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#1 to understand the difference.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the example links you are referencing.

Comment: I had some thoughts around an application which is waiting for incoming requests and then uses concurrency to deal with those, in some way similar to a load balancer. I just can't find any more simplistic self contained examples which would nicely demonstrate concurrency bringing a performance benefit.

Comment: Concurrency does not bring performance by itself, it's more about design and architecture of your application. It can make your program more scalable because concurrent programs can become faster very easily by executing everything in parallel just like Golang does with it's goroutines that are multiplexed on multiple threads. But goroutines do not make your program faster by themselves. So any code that use goroutines will be concurrent. Whether it will be faster when executed on multiple threads depends on the code itself.

Comment: @creker, yes, i think you've hit the nail on the head and it ultimately explains why there isn't really just a simple example.

Comment: @Phil, this question and the answer may be interesing to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104038/go-concurrency-chudnovkys-algorithm-slower-than-sync/ It has simple example that solves pretty popular problem. The initial version is concurrent but is even slower when executed in parallel on multiple cores. With the right approach you can make it both concurrent and faster when executed in parallel.

Comment: Also checkout some of the examples at https://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/

Comment: Little general for SO, but a common case is a server dealing with lots of Web requests coming in. Each takes some time, between CPU and waiting for the DB and network to do their things. You're relying on the system's ability to do multiple things at once (on one CPU or multiple). You aren't taking a big problem and splitting it into N CPU-limited threads, which is the prototypical case of CPU parallelism. If you parse it closely the distinction gets fuzzy; I think the larger point is that everyday uses of concurrency often aren't in the "split up one big task to use many cores" paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concurrency and parallelism are two related, but different things. The topic is broad, but let me briefly focus here on the speed.

Concurrency is related to how design and structure a program in a way that, if parallelism can be applied, then the software may run faster.

For example; if you have a loop such as

```
x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
for i := range x {
  x[i] *= x[i];
}
```

this program "feels" concurrent, because the read and write instructions that compute the square of each number in the array are logically independent one from the other. So, you could theoretically design your code in a concurrent way, for example by using goroutines:

```
x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
for i := range x {
  go func(j int) { x[j] *= x[j]; }(i)
}
wait_the_goroutines();
```

Assume for now that there are no data races in this example, and each update can be done independently. Well, the update of those values could be made in parallel, because the concurrent *design* allows it. With the old code, the update is serial *by design*.

Parallelism comes in when the computer (CPU, GPU, etc) is able to process multiple instructions at once, in the exact same time. If you have one core in your computer, the goroutines above are unlikely executed in parallel. If you have multiple cores, they *may* be executed in parallel - because they can be, but you have no *actual* control on how your computer's parallel hardware is used to execute the code in parallel. That's a task for the go runtime.

In some sense, concurrency is not used to increase execution speed: parallelism is. Concurrency is used to allow correct parallelization of code.

Therefore, you cannot really get such example, because even if you can get a "very concurrent" code, the execution speed is bounded to two things:

1. how much you can parallelize
2. how the go runtime will schedule the goroutines.

Comment: The latter remarks are related to Amdahl's Law (more of a useful guidance really), which can be paraphrased as: parallelism only gets you a speed-up in proportion to the amount of your program that still executes sequentially. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law